# How to write a Makefile rule with a wildcard character?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a phony rule which builds a `.h` file

I need to convert this into a `.vh` file

the rules would be something like

```
phony phony_rule: script2.pl
    perl script2.pl
    echo "Generation of file1.h and file2.h successful"

file1.vh: script.pl phony_rule
    perl $< -in file1.h -out @$

file2.vh: script.pl phony_rule
    perl $< -in file2.h -out $@
```

I was wondering if i can merge the two rules.

```
%.vh: script.pl phony_rule
    perl $< -in %.h -out $@
```

But seems like this does not work. I cant put `file1.h` and `file2.h` as dependency since it complains that no rule to make target `file1.h` and `file2.h`.

Can someone suggest how to get this to work?

Comment: Please show your complete makefile.  Apart from anything else `perl $< -in %.h -out $@` should probably be `perl $< -in $*.h -out $@`  and you should have the `%h` dependency in the specification as `%.vh: script.pl %.h phony_rule` .  Difficult to understand what you're trying to do though.

Comment: you should probably add `%.h` to the list of dependencies; then you can refer to it by `$(filter %.h,$^)` to avoid VPATH problems.

Comment: What you really need to show is the command you entered and the errors you got, and what you wanted to get instead.  "It seems like this does not work" is not an actionable problem.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$*` refers to the stem, i.e. whatever `%` matched in the pattern rule.

```
%.vh: script.pl %.h
    perl $< -in $*.h -out $@
```

(Notice also, that's `$@`, not `@$`. Equivalently, you could refer to the second dependency with `$(word 2,$^)` with GNU Make.)

You should probably spell out the actual dependency instead of calling the other rule a phony, though. There is nothing phony about a rule which creates files which your other targets depend on:

```
file1.h file2.h: script2.pl
    perl $<
```

As a further aside, you don't need to spell out `perl` before the script name if you make sure the script file has a proper [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and is marked executable (`chmod +x script.pl script2.pl`)

Comment: As a side note, I recommend to always explicitly call _perl_ instead of relying on shebangs, as the executable permission might be lost in source control and this would just cause hard-to-find errors. Even better, use `$(PERL)` and define `PERL := perl` so that target user could override it to the location of their choice when the location is non-standard.

Comment: Something is wrong with your source control if it doesn't let you control permissions. (That is not to say this was not common with older VCSes.) The other points are valid, but I guess also depend on your use case.

Comment: I am just talking about cases from my professional experience, where one edits the files in Windows (which don't really have executable permissions) and others cloning it in Linux environment, where this executable bit does not get set, because it was not set in git, because it was added in Windows, where it does not exist. Real life problem, simple solution, frustrated engineers.